# Batch Finished Message is not getting display

Tags: drupal-7, batch-processing, drupal-modules

I am using this code to display the message after completion of the batch operation in a process of import a CSV file in drupal 7. But my code is not working.

```
  function task_importer_form_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
if($success){
  drupal_set_message(t('@count items  processed.', array('@count' => count($results))));
}else{
// An error occurred.
// $operations contains the operations that remained unprocessed.
   $error_operation = reset($operations);
   $message = t('An error occurred while processing %error_operation with arguments: @arguments', array('%error_operation' => $error_operation[0], '@arguments' => print_r($error_operation[1], TRUE)));
   drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
 }
```

}

In the message, The need to display numbers of rows has been imported and some row has not to import successfully, with row number.

Comment: Please read documentation about good batch api practice https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/batch-api/overview and exemples https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/batch_example%21batch_example.module/7.x-1.x

Comment: I had tried already all of these and still hopeless.